# How are boolean expressions converted to NOR expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, boolean-algebra

What kind of rules help to convert an expression into a 3 input NOR expression? Do all variables have to be of the form (a+b+c)' + (d+e+f)'? What happens if there is an expression that is just (a')' that is to be made into a 3 input NOR - could you simply NOR it with itself?

More specifically I'm trying to get help in converting this equation into 3 input NOR:

```
  H = M + CR + CD'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about $\mathtt{NOR}(x,y,z) = \neg(x \lor y \lor z)$ then

\begin{align*}
\mathtt{NOT}(x) &= \mathtt{NOR}(x,x,x) \\
\mathtt{OR}(x,y,z) &= \mathtt{NOT}(\mathtt{NOR}(x,y,z)) \\
\mathtt{OR}(x,y) &= \mathtt{OR}(x,y,y) \\
\mathtt{AND}(x,y,z) &= \mathtt{NOR}(\mathtt{NOT}(x),\mathtt{NOT}(y), \mathtt{NOT}(z)) \\
\mathtt{AND}(x,y) &= \mathtt{AND}(x,y,y)
\end{align*}

Also, be aware that $(x \land y) \lor (x \land \neg y)$ is equivalent to $x \land (y \lor \neg y)$ and that simplifies to $x$.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve it for the expression above? I'd really appreciate the help, I've been at it for a while :(

Comment: @user1766888 I've almost handed you a solution on a silver platter, do some work yourself, would you?